# BeautifulSoup extract p, heading, li

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on a small python crawler and I am trying to extract every text stored inside `p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6` and `li` tags.

There is a method which is called soup.find_all() but it's only looking for one specific attribute according to the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

What would be the most efficient to extract text from those tags?

This is what I tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

VALID_TAGS = ['p', 'ul', 'li', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']

def scrape(text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        if tag.name in VALID_TAGS:
            ##stuck
```

Comment: find_all does take a list..
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? How about using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but I'm guessing it would be closer to this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = ...

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

tag_types = ["p", "ul", "li", ...]

for tag_type in tag_types:
    for tag in soup.find_all(tag_type):
        print(tag.text)
```